# How to mathematically describe a spin-0 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantization, bosons

I don't know all the technical things like Eigenstates. I want to know, mathematically written out for beginners, **how to make a quantum field theory of a scalar boson**.
To spare confusion- I understand how to do calculus yo to calculate two and have even solved EFE with some uncertainty . I just don't understand stuff like bra-ket notation and eigenstates. Which, if shown, I could learn pretty easily.
I want an answer in the style of "how do I quantize a classical field theory"- I had no clue how to do that but now I do. Just show me a description with an answer like this.

Comment: I've [moved the conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23566/discussion-on-question-by-damon-blevins-how-to-mathematically-describe-a-spin-0) to provide an avenue for discussion of the question, if anyone wants to do it. Comments are not for extended discussion though.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty darn difficult to describe quantum field theory without technical details but here goes nothing.

What we want is some field, $\phi$, which satisfies the equations associated with a scalar (spin 0) fields such as the Higgs. One such equation is the Klein-Gordon equation, which is related to the relationship between energy, momentum and mass found in special relativity. By writing the solutions to this equation in a certain way (called Fourier decomposition), you can show that the fields, and their associated momenta, must satisfy certain relationships. This so far is just a field theory. What makes it a quantum field theory is a process called canonical quantisation. This imposes ore constraints on the way fields behave. Once these constraints have been imposed you can find all sorts of results like the energy spectrum of the field, and the spins of the particles (in this case bosons, had we wanted fermions we would have used the Dirac equation).

What I have described here is the simple case of a non-interacting field which can be solved exactly. For realistic theories (e.g. QED) the process involves perturbation theory (i.e. the use of Feynman diagrams), which again is technical.

All these processes involve quite a bit of maths, particularly linear algebra (matrices and operators) and calculus. If you fancy finding how it's actually done you could look at a set of notes online (David Tong's notes are great, Kasper Peeters notes go on to discuss some interesting topics like string theory and renormalisation). However,as was mentioned in the comments, if you've not yet seen a mathematical formulation of normal quantum mechanics and the relevant background mathematics (topics covered in the 2nd year of university onward) then a proper understanding of the construction of a theory is pretty difficult.

Comment: I've deleted the comments since this is not the place to hold discussions.